# Problem with Laravel, Apache and DigitalOcean (too_many_redirects)

Tags: laravel, apache, digital-ocean

I have a problem with my laravel project, I installed in DigitalOcean, all the instalacions work fine my Php, composer, postgresql all work fine.

I created my virtualhost in Apache like this.

````
``` <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     ServerName hidrofracweb.com
     ServerAlias www.example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/hidrofrac/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/hidrofrac/public >
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>```
````

and in my project route are like this.

web.php

````
    ```Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
    Route::post('departamentos/departamento', 'DepartamentoController@index')->name('departamento');
    Route::post('usuarios/usuario', 'UsuarioController@index')->name('usuario');
    Route::post('registroproducto', 'UsuarioController@guardartipopro');
    Route::post('registroproubicaion', 'UsuarioController@guardartipoubicacion');
    Route::post('usuarios/usuario', 'UsuarioController@index')->name('usuario');
    Route::post('usuarios/gpproducto','UsuarioController@tproducto');
    Route::post('registrausuario','UsuarioController@store');
    Route::post('usuarios/permiso', 'UsuarioController@permisousuario');
    Route::post('registrapermiso', 'UsuarioController@permisosuser');```
````

when I work in my local computer and open navigator I run my project like this.

http://localhost/hidrofrac/public/login

Works fine...

But when I run my project in my virtual machine with my ip, get this error.

```
page not working too many redirects
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

can someone help me please?

Comment: You're not properly creating your virtual host that's causing too many redirects.

Comment: This should answer  your question: https://serverfault.com/a/520201